# Upgrading PostgreSQL 9.3 to 9.5

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I want to upgrade version 9.3 to 9.5 but after some steps I find that I upgraded to version 10, but I'm looking to go from 9.3 to 9.5.

When I type the `pg_lsclusters` command I find myself with three:

[image]

I used `sudo pg_dropcluster 9.5 main --stop` and `sudo pg_dropcluster 10 main --stop` to stop both, and `sudo pg_upgradecluster 9.3 main` command to set the 9.3 cluster to the latest version.

But I want to go to 9.5 instead of 10. The result after what I'm typing is:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you drop cluster for version 9.5, you may upgrade your 9.3 to 9.5 with this command:

`sudo pg_upgradecluster -v 9.5 9.3 main`

If you omit `-v 9.5` it will upgrade the cluster to the latest postgresql version you have installed. For more information, type `man pg_upgradecluster`.

Now, since you already upgraded to 10, you have to stop the new cluster (version 10) and start the 9.3 again. You may do this with commands:

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster 10 main stop
sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.3 main start
```